# selecting a value using a conditional statement based on a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, if-statement, tuples, conditional-statements

I have a list of tuples converted from a dictionary. I am looking to compare a conditional value against the list of tuples(values) whether it is higher or lower starting from the beginning on the list. When this conditional value is lower than a tuple's(value) I want to use that specific tuple for further coding.

Please can somebody give me an insight into how this is achieved?

I am relatively new to coding, self-learning and I am not 100% sure the example would run but for the sake of demonstrating I have tried my best.

```
`tuple_list = [(12:00:00, £55.50), (13:00:00, £65.50), (14:00:00, £75.50), (15:00:00, £45.50), (16:00:00, £55.50)]

 conditional_value = £50

 if conditional_value != for x in tuple_list.values()
     y = 0
     if conditional_value < tuple_list(y)
         y++1
     else
         ///"return the relevant value from the tuple_list to use for further coding. I would be 
         looking to work with £45.50"///`
```

Thank you.

Comment: Still a bit confusing, could you add the return values you expect to see?

Comment: Your tuple list seems to be invalid, does it contains values as strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just form a new list with a condition:

```
tuple_list = [("12:00:00", 55.50), ("13:00:00", 65.50), ("14:00:00", 75.50), ("15:00:00", 45.50), ("16:00:00", 55.50)]

threshold = 50
below = [tpl for tpl in tuple_list if tpl[1] < threshold]
print(below)
```

Which yields

```
[('15:00:00', 45.5)]
```

Note that I added quotation marks and removed the currency sign to be able to compare the values. If you happen to have the `£` in your actual values, you'll have to preprocess (stripping) them before.

Comment: brilliant! thank you for your help :) is there a way to find the location of this tuple? say if the tuple_list was much greater?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, this should be what you're looking for:

```py
for key, value in tuple_list:
    if conditional_value < value:
        continue  # Skips to next in the list.
    else:
        # Do further coding.
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, that looks a lot more accurate and simplified then what I had. 'if conditional_value != for x in tuple_list.values()'  this was to initially check to see if the conditional_value already exists in the tuple. Would this line of code work before your ''for statement'' suggestion? Also, how would you create the £45.50 object for the 'else' section? would it just be ''tuple_list(value)''?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
tuple_list = [("12:00:00", 55.50), ("13:00:00", 65.50), ("14:00:00", 75.50), ("15:00:00", 45.50), ("16:00:00", 55.50)]
conditional_value = 50
new_tuple_list = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] > conditional_value, tuple_list))
```

This code will return a new_tuple_list with all items that there value us greater then the conditional_value.